# java multiple images with loop

Tags: image, javafx

I would like to create more then one image with a loop. Yet, it doesn't seem to work this way. The problem is that an image can't have a number as a name. Is there a way to do this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < getObjects().size(); i++) {
            Image i = new Image(getObjects().get(i).getImagePath()));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making an ArrayList of type Image and you can store all your images there

```
ArrayList<Image> imageArrayList = new ArrayList<Image>();
for(int i = 0; i < getObjects().size(); i++) {
    imageArrayList.add(new Image(getObjects().get(i).getImagePath());
}
```

If you are just starting with java don't want this to be as confusing when returning to the code maybe use something like this

```
ArrayList<Image> imageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();//Creates the list that will store images
for(int i = 0; i < getObjects().size(); i++) {
    Image image = new Image(getObjects().get(i).getImagePath());//Create the image you want to store
    imageArrayList.add(image);//Add that image to the arraylist
}
```